# selenium driver returns null when calling from base class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception, cucumber

I have one base class with setup of webdriver using @Before and @After cucumber annotations. I extended my base class to other classes to share the webdriver.
my other class execute before my setup class and returns null exception.
below code snippet
**Base Class/parent class code**

```
package StepDef;

import Util.Constants;
import Util.GetConfigProp;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class BaseUtil {
    public WebDriver driver;
    GetConfigProp prop = new GetConfigProp();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        System.setProperty(Constants.CHROME_DRIVER_PROPERTY, "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to(prop.readProp());

    }
    @After
     public void quitApplication(){
         driver.quit();

    }
}
```

**This is my **child class****

```
    package Pages;

import StepDef.BaseUtil;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

public class LoginPage extends BaseUtil {
    @FindBy(how = How.ID,using = "user-name")
    public WebElement txtUserNameBox;

    @FindBy(how = How.ID,using = "password")
    public WebElement txtPassword;

    public LoginPage() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);

    }

    public void login(String userName, String password)
    {
        txtUserNameBox.sendKeys(userName);
        txtPassword.sendKeys(password);

    }
}
```

**This is my step definition class if needed**

```
    package StepDef;

import Pages.LoginPage;
import cucumber.api.java8.En;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyStepdefs implements En {
    public MyStepdefs() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        LoginPage loginObj=new LoginPage();
        Given("^the user is on home page$", () -> {
        });
        When("^user enters ([^\\\"]*) and ([^\\\"]*) correctly$", (String username,String password) -> {
            loginObj.login(username,password);
        });
        Then("^user login successfully$", () -> {
        });
    }
}
```

**This is **exception****

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
    at Pages.LoginPage.login(LoginPage.java:26)
    at StepDef.MyStepdefs.lambda$new$1(MyStepdefs.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

I am not sure where is the problem.
Thanks for help.

Comment: I think @Before never got invoked. Did you see the browser open and navigate to the url ?  if you are using cucumber hooks, then you have to add those to the glue path on your runner file.

Comment: yes its opening and closing the browser. This is the problem why returning the null exception even the driver invoking. I debugged and got the LoginPage class execute before hook, dnt know why

Answer (score 0):

Do not extend your page class from test class. JUnit instantiate an object from test class where the driver field is then injected using code from `@Before`.

Then when you initizlize you page object it creates **different** object where your webdriver is still null.

Comment: Thanks. How to use shared driver if not extended the class? Can you please let me know. Thanks

Comment: https://webelement.click/en/cucumber_java_8_selenium_pageobject_picocontainer_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

```
 LoginPage loginObj=new LoginPage(driver);
```